# Ubuntu 10.10 graphics card

Tags: linux, graphics-card, ubuntu-10.10, dell-studio

I have Dell studio 15 laptop. I have installed a ubuntu 10.10. When ever I boot Ubuntu it comes up with a error message saying graphics card driver not found or not dedicated. But I have updated my graphics card and also wifi driver.I am not getting the advance graphics option and also I am not able to activate the feel and look of the desktop.

Please suggest me.

Comment: /me hates ubuntu 10.10 and upwards. /me uses 10.04 on each my laptop with a few fixes for sound card and appearance. although, /me uses 10.04 with great success.

Comment: Maybe this question should be posted in http://askubuntu.com/ instead of superuser.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but unfortunately there's no migration vote option for askubuntu yet.

Comment: what graphics card do you have? have you tried any other ubuntu release on it before?

Comment: Agreed with 10.04 for laptops especially. I spent a day and a half trying to make the Vostro work gave me happy running 10.10 before giving up.  The drivers / kernel situation is an absolute MESS. Upgrade things in the wrong order (which Apt very easily lets you do) and you have a command line brick.

Comment: We really need more information about **your hardware and the error messages produced**. The output of `lspci` and the last lines of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and `/var/log/dmesg` might be a start.

Comment: Could you include the video card specs for your model of your Dell Studio 15 laptop? It seems the Studio 15 comes with either Intel integrated graphics or an ATI video card and not all Studio 15's use same model of graphics card depending on when it came out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't yet, try installing the closed driver via Menu -> System -> Administration -> Additional Drivers. It should give you a notice about the ATI FGLRX driver.

Comment: Assuming we are talking about an ATI card here.